# Two different gallery in one gallery

Tags: views, media

I created two gallery with **different content type** and **different views** (gallery1 & gallery2)...and i want to make it in one gallery containing **one image of each gallery** (one of gallery1 & one of gallery2)...   please help me with video or something else...and tell me what i have to do ?              i use Drupal 7               & thx

Comment: does your views are of type block or page?

Comment: thx, my views type is page.

Comment: touha what your both views are about you can combine them in a view. view has options content is one of 'a' or 'b' content type

Comment: yeah i know but my problem is i want to make gallery containing one of each two gallery, do you understand what i want now!!!... i created gallery contaning all the other gallery but i want to make filter to take one image from all the other gallery. & thx again

Comment: can you tell me how can i take one of gallery 1 and one of gallery 2 with a filter or something else !!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new View and add the two content type in **Filter criteria**

Add the two image fields in **Fields** section

Under **Multiple field settings** set "1" in display option for both images

[image]

Select your Format for views, hope it helps you!!